# Remove bullet when hit a wall

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, platform

I'm making an AS3 platform game where the player can shoot some bullets.

When the bullet is touching an enemy, the enemy die and the bullet is removed.

I've succeed do to that but now I'd like to remove the bullet if it hit a wall and I can't figure out how to do so.

So far, here's my code for removing the bullet when touching an enemy :

```
public function checkCollisions() {

            // enemies
            for(var i:int=enemies.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                if (hero.mc.hitTestObject(enemies[i].mc)) {

                    // is the hero jumping down onto the enemy?
                    if (hero.inAir && (hero.dy > 0)) {
                        enemyDie(i);
                    } else {
                        heroDie();
                    }
                }

            for (var j:int = 0; j < bulletList.length; j++) // for each bullet in the bulletList
                {
                    if (enemies[i].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )
                    {
                        trace("Bullet and Enemy are colliding");
                        enemyDie(i)
                        bulletList[j].removeSelf();
                    }

                }
            }
```

I've defined my wall and floor like this :

```
public function examineLevel() {
            fixedObjects = new Array();
            otherObjects = new Array();
            for(var i:int=0;i<this.gamelevel.numChildren;i++) {
                var mc = this.gamelevel.getChildAt(i);

                // add floors and walls to fixedObjects
                if ((mc is Floor) || (mc is Wall)) {
                    var floorObject:Object = new Object();
                    floorObject.mc = mc;
                    floorObject.leftside = mc.x;
                    floorObject.rightside = mc.x+mc.width;
                    floorObject.topside = mc.y;
                    floorObject.bottomside = mc.y+mc.height;
                    fixedObjects.push(floorObject);
}
}
```

I've tried to put this in my checkCollisions function but it's not working :

```
for(var k:int=0;k<fixedObjects.length;k++)
                    {
                        if (fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) ){
                            trace("hit wall");
                        }
```

Do you know what do I have to put in order to remove the bullet when it's touching a wall (or floor) ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `fixedObjects` holds references to `Object` instances. However, `hitTestObject(obj)` is a public function of the `DisplayObject` class, and the `obj` parameter needs to be an instance of `DisplayObject`.

If the code snippet you provided is exactly the same as what you used in your game, there should be runtime error messages generated.

Could you please verify whether this is the cause of failing to detect collision?

Comment: There is, indeed, a runtime error message. It's Error #1006: hitTestObject is not a function.
 at PlatformGame/checkCollisions()[E:\Applis\Brousse En Folie Plateforme\PlatformGame.as:366]
 at PlatformGame/gameLoop()[E:\Applis\Brousse En Folie Plateforme\PlatformGame.as:198]      line 366 is if (fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) ){

Comment: You may try to add `floorObject.mc` rather than `floorObject` into `fixedObjects`. This should then work as long as `fixedObjects` is not being used in other sections.

Comment: hmmm...? where ? cause if I change  fixedObjects.push(floorObject); by  fixedObjects.push(floorObject.mc); it is not working (my character is falling off the stage)

Comment: Alright, then you are using `floorObject` somewhere else in your code. Without modifying `fixedObjects` array, you can replace `if (fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) ){` by `if (fixedObjects[k].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) ){`, and see if it works.

Comment: Perfect ! It's working ! Thanks !!! (but do you know why it make this error in the runtime if I add `bulletList[j].removeSelf();` where `trace("hit wall")` is ? : `error #2007 parameter hitTestObject must be non-null )`

Comment: I think it's because the code wants to do 2 things. `if (enemies[i].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )` AND `if (fixedObjects[k].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) ){` So for one of these he found hitTestObject as null

Comment: `fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j])` generates error, as `fixedObjects[k]` is an `Object`, but there is not a function called `hitTestObject(something)` in the `Object` class.

Comment: So why there is no error for `if (enemies[i].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )` ? What must I do in order to make `fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j])` work ?

Comment: In the line `enemies[i].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j])`, by just looking at the variable names you used, it seems `enemies[i]` is an instance of one of your self-defined class, and there is a variable `mc` holding a reference of the `MovieClip` instance of your enemy object. As `MovieClip` is a sub-class of `DisplayObject`, and `hitTestObject(obj)` is a public function defined in the class `DisplayObject`, so the line `enemies[i].mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j])` is valid.

Comment: If you want `fixedObjects[k].hitTestObject(bulletList[j])` to work as expected, `fixedObjects` should be an array of `DisplayObject` or `MovieClip` instances. Currently in your code, `fixedObjects` is an array of `Object` instances. You will have to change the data type of `fixedObjects`, but doing so leads to other problems, as some other pieces of code are relying on this array. If the above solution works, I suggest not to change anything else. The code should be human-readable enough.

Comment: Maybe I could add a clip on stage with an instance (like "test_mc") and put something like `test_mc.hitTestObject(bulletList[j])`

Comment: That's nice to experiment with different possible solutions, though it may seem a bit redundant in this case.